# Alternative integration limits in a Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

The unilateral Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is $\int_0^\infty e^{st} f(t)   \mathrm{d}t$.

If we define the transform as $\int_{a}^\infty e^{st} f(t)   \mathrm{d}t$, would it conserve all the nice properties of the true Laplace transform (e.g., the convolution theorem)?

How would its inverse be?

Comment: forget the uni-lateral Laplace transform $F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt$ and learn only the bilateral Laplace tranform $$\mathcal{L}[h(t)](s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t) e^{-st} dt$$

hence $$ \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt = \mathcal{L}[f(t)1_{t >0}](s)$$
while
$$ \int_a^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt = \mathcal{L}[f(t)1_{t >a}](s)$$

Comment: (and your teacher is bad)

Comment: I'm self-taught :,-( !

Answer (score 0):

This is what you get when you have a unit step function.  (Heaviside function).

If $\int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} dt = F(s)$ then $\int_a^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} dt = e^{-as} F(s)$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean its inverse in time domain, then it is 
$$u(t - a) f(t)$$
where
$$u = \begin{cases}
1, & t \geq a \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

And yes, the convolution theorem still applies.